# How to chain make object with method call?

Tags: javascript, rebol

Let's say I have

```
WORLD: make object! [
      people: make Object! []
      cars: make Object! []
      factories: make Object! []
      create: func[][print "new world"]
]
```

How can I chain with the create method? something like this doesn't work.

```
(make WORLD[])/create
```

This is the JavaScript I would like to emulate

```
(new WORLD()).create()
```

Comment: I dont know anything about rebol.. but the way it works in javascript is you simply `return` the object at the end of the function call.

Comment: thanks I have no problem in javascript I want to do same in rebol but fail to see how :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idiom in this case is `do get in`:

```
>> do get in make object! [a: does [42]] 'a
== 42
```

`IN` returns the word `'a` in the object's context. `GET` retrieves the value bound to `'a` word (in that context). Finally as we expected the value returned by `GET` to be a function, we just call that function using `DO`.

For your example given, this would therefore look as follows:

```
do get in make WORLD [] 'create
```

As per Hostile Fork's suggestion in the comments, here is a fully parenthesised version of the last expression, to make function arity explicit:

```
do (get (in (make WORLD []) 'create))
```

Comment: I often think that in answering questions which might be read by non-native Rebol speakers that it's best to write it first parenthesized and avoid cool-but-unfamiliar features like `does`.  Such as `do (get in (make object! [a: func [][return 42]]) 'a)`.  Then immediately afterward say "the parentheses aren't necessary" and show it in a more idiomatic Rebol, to convey it works both ways and show off cool features.

Comment: Oh my what a horrible syntax :) why can't rebol do something like in foreach ... element/:i ?

Comment: Also I don't understand how I would apply this to method call (create method in my example) with your get in ?

Comment: Updated the answer to show how to use this with your specific example.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is working a little more with REBOL's grain, that style of chaining really isn't to REBOL's strength:

```
WORLD: make object! [
      people: make Object! []
      cars: make Object! []
      factories: make Object! []
      create: does [print "new world"]
]

make WORLD [create]
```

Alternatively, if you're looking for a response from create (which you won't get in this instance as 'print returns unset!):

```
result: do bind [create] make WORLD []
```

It's perhaps a little clunky compared with chaining, but then chaining is old school language.  Using 'bind is like having access to black magic.